# Как вывести множество изображений при помощи Javafx

Tags: javafx, imageview

Проблема заключается в том, что я не могу вывести много изображений(imageView). Для того, чтобы вывести изображение, мне нужно создать новый экземпляр класса ImageView. Но когда я пытаюсь создать множество(больше 200) таких объектов и запихнуть их в ArrayList, то вылетает OutOfMemoryError. Пожалуйста, подскажите что с этим делать, может есть какой-то другой способ вывести множество изображений при помощи javafx?

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы отобразить 200+ изображений, не обязательно создавать 200+ экземпляров `ImageView`. Дело в том, что `ImageView` — пользовательский элемент управления (`Control`) и всего лишь является контейнером для изображений. Его основное предназначение не в том, чтобы *хранить* данные, а в том, чтобы *представлять* их пользователю. Как только мы начинаем рассматривать данный класс как *контейнер* для изображений, сразу же возникают два вопроса: как изображения в этом контейнере отображать и как обойтись минимальным количеством контейнеров с целью экономии ресурсов.

Для демонстрации общего случая годится класс `ListView`.

[image: Пример работы ListView]

Положим, необходимо отобразить массив строк вида `strings = [item 1, item 2, ...]`, с использованием класса `ListView` и контейнера `TextView` по порядку их расположения в массиве. Таким образом в видимой области экрана единовременно находятся семь контейнеров (серые прямоугольники). В начальном состоянии каждый из семи контейнеров отображает одну строку из массива по индексам 0-6.

При прокрутке снизу вверх самый верхний контейнер перестает быть видимым **(1)**, после чего `ListView` берет данные следующего по порядку элемента из массива и отображает их в этом контейнере **(2)**. Далее контейнер снова отображается на экране **(3)**, но уже снизу и с новыми данными. Таким образом сколько бы ни было строк (сравнительно небольших по объему) в массиве `strings`, в памяти всегда будет находиться минимально необходимое количество контейнеров (сравнительно больших) для их отображения — в данном примере семь. При этом "логикой перестановки" контейнеров занимается сам `ListView`.

Исходя из Вашего вопроса предположу, что для отображения карты Вы планируете использовать общепринятую модель пользовательского взаимодействия — горизонтальная и вертикальная прокрутка, при этом сама карта состоит из множества квадратных изображений. Из этого вытекает необходимость использовать контейнер, который способен отображать сетку контролов и вести себя с ними так же, как и `ListView`. Насколько мне известно, подходящего класса нет в стандартном пакете javafx, однако он есть в библиотеке [ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/) и называется он `GridView`.

**Пример отображения 500-сот изображений в `GridView` только с вертикальной прокруткой**

[image: Скриншот программы]

**Main.java**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("MainView.fxml"));

        Parent root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

**MainController.java**

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import org.controlsfx.control.GridView;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class MainController implements Initializable{
    //контейнер для всей карты
    public GridView<MapTile> gridView;

    //класс-посредник, отображающий URL изображения в ImageView
    public ImagesAdapter gridViewAdapter;

    //Все изображения, составляющие карту
    private ObservableList<MapTile> mapTiles = createData();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources){
        gridViewAdapter = new ImagesAdapter(gridView);
        gridViewAdapter.setData(mapTiles);
    }

    //Создадим ссылки на 500 изображений с номерами от 1 до 500 для демонстрации
    private ObservableList<MapTile> createData(){
        ObservableList<MapTile> tiles = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for(int i = 1; i <= 500; i++){
            tiles.add(new MapTile("http://via.placeholder.com/300?text=" + i));
        }
        return tiles;
    }
}
```

**ImagesAdapter.java**

```
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import org.controlsfx.control.GridCell;
import org.controlsfx.control.GridView;

import java.io.IOException;

//Класс служит для передачи объектов MapTile в GridView (через GridCell)
class ImagesAdapter{
    //счетчик созданных ячеек GridView
    private static int cellCounter = 0;

    private final GridView<MapTile> mapView;

    public ImagesAdapter(GridView<MapTile> mapView){
        this.mapView = mapView;
        //Фабрика, создающая новые ImageCell при необходимости
        mapView.setCellFactory(new Callback<GridView<MapTile>, GridCell<MapTile>>(){
            @Override
            public GridCell<MapTile> call(GridView<MapTile> param){
                return new ImageCell();
            }
        });
    }

    public void setData(ObservableList<MapTile> mapTiles){
        mapView.setItems(mapTiles);
    }

    //одна ячейка GridView
    class ImageCell extends GridCell<MapTile>{
        //ImageView, отображающийся в ячейке
        private ImageCellView viewController;

        ImageCell(){
            //Создаем ImageView для ячейки
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ImageCellView.fxml"));
            try {
                Pane root = loader.load();
                viewController = loader.getController();
                viewController.root = root;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //При очень быстрой прокрутке может создаваться дополнительное количество ячеек
            //В java заруднительно учесть удаление объекта, поэтому счетчик при быстрой
            //прокрутке будет показывать большее количество объектов, чем при медленной.
            //Тем не менее в MemoryView при установке Breakpoint'a на данное выражение
            //всегда будет видно реальное количество используемых ImageCell (ImageView)
            System.out.println("Created new ImageCell: " + cellCounter++);
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(MapTile item, boolean empty){
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            //Здесь необходимо либо очистить ячейку, либо отобразить в ней новые данные

            if (empty || item == null) {
                //чистим
                setGraphic(null);
                viewController.clear();
            } else {
                //кладем новое изображение
                viewController.update(item.getUrl());
                setGraphic(viewController.root);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ImageCellView.java**

```
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

//ImageView с небольшой обвязкой для отображения в ячейке GridView
public class ImageCellView implements Initializable{
    public Pane root;
    public ImageView loadedImage;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources){
        //no-op
    }

    //Метод для удаления старых данных
    public void clear(){
        loadedImage.getImage().cancel();
        loadedImage.setImage(null);
    }

    //Метод для отображения новых данных
    public void update(String url){
        loadedImage.setImage(new Image(url, true));
    }
}
```

**MapTile.java**

```
//Класс для хранения информации об одном кусочке карты
public class MapTile{
    //Ссылка на изображение
    private String tileUrl;

    public MapTile(String url){
        this.tileUrl = url;
    }

    public String getUrl(){
        return tileUrl;
    }
}
```

**MainView.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import org.controlsfx.control.GridView?>
<HBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      fx:controller="MainController"
      prefHeight="400.0"
      prefWidth="600.0">

    <GridView fx:id="gridView"
              prefHeight="400.0"
              prefWidth="600.0"/>

</HBox>
```

**ImageCellView.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<Pane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      fx:controller="ImageCellView"
      prefHeight="400.0"
      prefWidth="600.0">

    <ImageView fx:id="loadedImage"
               fitHeight="100.0"
               fitWidth="100.0"/>

</Pane>
```

Comment: А что делать, если я хочу разом вывести 200+ картинок(без прокрутки),размер тайла 16x16, а размер окна 320x320, т.е. получается 20 тайлов в ширину, 20 тайлов в высоту? Для этого есть какой-нибудь способ? А может я вообще выбрал не подходящую библиотеку для создания игры?

Comment: Я попробовал бы использовать для этого ``Canvas``, отрисовывая на нем объекты ``Image`` по координатам

Comment: А вы бы могли скинуть какой-нибудь код для примера?

Comment: @ПавелЧемармазович, вот здесь есть пример отрисовки изображений на ``Canvas`` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28100060/javafx-canvas-draw-image-with-transparency, работу с ``opacity`` в нем можно опустить.

Comment: Да, но проблема в том,что при помощи метода drawImage() можно отрисовать только объект типа Image,а не ImageView( Может вы посоветуете какие-нибудь другие библиотеки для работы с графикой?

Comment: Других библиотек не посоветую, поскольку не знаю таковых. Почему вам необходимо использовать именно ``ImageView`` и почему бы не использовать ``Image``?

Comment: Дело в том, что я работаю со спрайт-листом и тайлсетом, т.е. мне надо выводить часть картинки на экран,а не всю картинку.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос больше данных: какие картинки вы пытаетесь отобразить и каким образом, приведите примеры того, как загружаете картинки. Лучшим вариантом будет привести  [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) кода, который вы хотели бы починить. Так же советую указать в вопросе все дополнительные условия, которые влияют на эту часть вашей программы